# How to find the maximum value in a zeros array in python?

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to find the maximum value in two array of zeros which I have populated using a loop as follows:

```
dydx = zeros(n+1)
error = zeros(n+1)


for i in range(n):
    dydx[i]=(y[i+1]-y[i])/h
    error[i]= cos(i)-dydx[i]
```

If I try to find `i = np.argmax(dydx)` I get a non callable error?

Comment: Please include the actual error text.  Also, `n`, `h`, and `y` are undefined.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using `np.max(dxdy)`.

It should give you the max value.

Comment: Thank you so much, that worked! Not sure if you can ask questions in the comments but how would you find which x value this is for?

Comment: Just do something like this: `dxdy.tolist().index(np.max(dxdy))`. Is this clear or you want me to write it simpler? Basically, you just transform numpy array to python list and there is a list method `index` which takes in a list element and returns index of that element in the list. I would appreciate +1 :)

Comment: Wow that worked. I have been trying to do this for like the past 3 days. And I think I understand it, somewhat. I tried to +1 but it says 'Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation points are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score. I hope it worked?

Comment: Thanks :) I'm glad I could help.

Comment: You're welcome. Now I just need you to do my whole project for me.

Comment: haha sure ;) If you need anything else, just write here in the comments and I'll try to answer you

Comment: ok, so how do I assign values from an array in a for loop? And can you put two variables in a for loop as in 'for i in range(n) and also for j in array(c): ... ?' Does that even make sense? Basically, the question is to change values for the h  in the equation for specified value of x. Let me know if I should clarify. Thankyou!

Comment: Can you write what is the `n`, `x` and `h`? Are those variables arrays or scalars or what? You can do loop in a loop like this: `for i in n:\n for j in c:\n do something`. Here where is `\n` you should hit enter.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to solve a Euler's value. I.e. something like this?

```
import numpy as np

x0=0
y0=1
xf=10
n=101
deltax=(xf-x0)/(n-1)
x=np.linspace(x0,xf,n)
y = np.zeros( [n] )
y[0]=y0

for i in range(1,n):
    y[i] = deltax*(-y[i-1] + np.sin(x[i-1]))+y[i-1]

#for i in range ( n ) :
#    print ( x[i] , y[i] )

print(max(y))
```

[REF](https://faculty.washington.edu/heathml/2018spring307/euler_method.pdf)

Comment: Yup. Thank you for your answer, and also the attached reference. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Is the above your full code, and are you using `zeros()` as a function or a list, `zeros=[]`? If it is a list, it cannot be called. When I tried the following, no error is returned:

```
def zeros():
  n=0
  dydx = zeros(n+1)
  error = zeros(n+1)


  for i in range(n):
      dydx[i]=(y[i+1]-y[i])/h
      error[i]= cos(i)-dydx[i]

  print (i = np.argmax(dydx))
```